# jQuery multiple events and multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use multiple selectors and multiple events in jQuery?

I want to combine the following:

```
$('#submit-modal').click(function() {
$('#modal-form').submit(function() {
```

Into something like (or similar):

```
$('#submit-modal, #modal-form').on('click', 'submit', function() {
```

I've tried this, but it is not working.

#### Update (more of what I'm looking to accomplish):

```
$('#submit-modal').click().$('#modal-form').submit(function() {
```

I only want the `click()` attached to the `#submit-modal` and `submit()` attached to the `#modal-form` but if either is initiated it runs the same function.

Comment: Separate the events by a space instead of a comma like 'click submit'

Comment: Not hard... `$('#submit-modal, #modal-form').on('click submit', function() {`

Comment: Thanks! That did it, but not the result I am looking for. Because now when I click anywhere in the form it submits. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to trigger the form submission from the click event so that the code related to form submission is present only in one palce.

```
$('#submit-modal').click(function() {
    $('#modal-form').submit();// $('#modal-form')[0].submit();
});
$('#modal-form').submit(function() {
    //do the submit code here
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. This will do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$("#submit-modal, #modal-form").on("click submit", function() {..});
```

This made that the anonimous function executes when you click or submit in #submit-modal or #modal-form

Comment: Thanks, that does work but my logic was messed up because now when I click anywhere in the form it submits. Any way to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, separating the calling function of click and submit.
When you attach the event click to a element of the DOM, it execute when you click in everywhere of this element.
Answering your new cuestion of the update, you looking something like:

var myfunction = function () {...}
$("#submit-modal").on("click", myfunction);
$("#modal-form").on("submit", myfunction);

Answer (score 0):

Yah, you might better off keeping each event with each selector, unless they trigger by the same event.